# How to create updatable views in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, updatable-views

How to make an updatable view in TSQL. Please provide simple examples that I can base my solution on.

*Lately I was helping my friend with TSQL, and he asked me about updatable views. I thought it will be a good idea to leave my solution here for the future as a quick lookup.*

For a good reference please take a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

I am providing a very basic working example.

```
--Here is our base table
CREATE TABLE  [test_table]
(
   [a]   int primary key, 
   [b]   varchar(40),
   [c]   bigint,
   [d]   varchar(20),
)
GO

--Here is our view to the table
CREATE VIEW [test_view]     As SELECT b,a,d FROM test_table
GO

--As an example insert few entries
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (0, 'abc', 2, '2011-10-13')
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1, 'abc', 2, '2011-10-13')
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (3, 'abc', 2, '2011-10-13')

--Check if everything works fine
SELECT * FROM test_table 
SELECT * FROM test_view
GO
```

Since table and the view are fullfiling the msdn requierments ([lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx)), I am able to do the following on the view:

```
UPDATE test_view SET b = 'xyz', d = '2011-10-14' where a = 0
INSERT test_view VALUES ('xyz', 2, '2011-10-14')
DELETE test_view where a = 3
GO

SELECT * FROM test_table 
SELECT * FROM test_view
GO
```

***Important:*** Bulk insert is allowed as well.

Good luck with programming.